# Set jquery cookie time after page loaded open automatically 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How to set jquery cookie time after page loaded open automatically 5 seconds & close after 5 seconds, How can I do it ?? Please help me.

**My JS code :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-welcome-message').firstVisitPopup({
      cookieName : 'homepage',
      showAgainSelector: '#show-message'
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will create WP plugin. when page loaded then show a popup only once per visitor.

Comment: If my answer helped, you should mark it so others can find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. Are you wanting to first check for a cookie and if the cookie doesn't exist wait 5 seconds after the page loads to display a message? Then close the message after 5 more seconds?

Regardless, you can use a [Javascript setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to execute code after *x* number of milliseconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeOut;
    // use setTimeout to call the open function after 5 seconds
    timeOut = setTimeout(openMessage, 5000);

    function openMessage() {
        // your code to display message

        // the setTimeout again to run the close function in 5 seconds
        timeOut = setTimeout(closeMessage, 5000);
    };

    function closeMessage() {
        // your code to close the message
    }
});
```

This should point you in the right direction. If you clarify your post, I might be able to help further.